# Terraform partially interprets a decimal number

Tags: terraform

I would like to know if some of you encountered the following issue;
While I'm trying to upgrade my EKS cluster to version 1.20 with the following variable-

```
eks_version = 1.20
```

This picture shows the result, terraform converts 1.20 to 1.2-
[image]

For some reason, terraform not take into account the total decimal number, resulting in an error;

```
Error: error updating EKS Cluster (stage) version: InvalidParameterException: unsupported Kubernetes version
```

P.S
I tried to use the format function as well

```
eks_version = format("%.2s", 1.20)
```

With the same output.
Any ideas on how to make terraform take into account the whole decimal number?

Comment: You would want to specify the version as a string `eks_version = "1.20"`.

Comment: If you are using any kind of IDE to write terraform code, hovering over the argument should show you the expected type.

Comment: [Semantic versioning](https://semver.org/) numbers are not decimals. They are 2 or more integer numbers, separated by periods. For example `1.20.0` cannot be represented as a decimal. By the same token, `1.20` and `1.2` have the same decimal value, but represent entirely different semantic version. Thus you should never use decimals to store semantic version numbers, you should always use strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ervin's comment is correct.

The answer is to stop [formatting](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/format) it using this method.

The format spec of `%.2f` says to limit the input `1.20` with a width of 2.

If you want a specific version, remove the call to the format function.

Answer (score 1):

I had to make this variable a string, not a number.

I had to change my variable definition to string:

```
variable "eks_version" {
  type    = string
  default = "1.20"
}
```